# Two 32 bit(signed) Fixed Point addition-Overflow

Tags: overflow, fixed, point, addition, xilinx

There are two,32bit(signed) fixed point values with no. of bits 32 and binary points 16.

When these 2 are added,there is an overflow.

How this can be fixed with a code or can this be fixed without code too just by changing the block parameters ??

This is implemented in Xilinx,an mcode will be used.

Comment: What behaviour would you want? Saturation, or keeping full precision?

Comment: Thanks for your response.I am looking for Saturation

Comment: "An mcode will be used", I'm assuming you are using HDL Coder then?

Comment: I can use either mcode or with the available toolbox.But mcode is more appropriate here.HDL coder is used at the final stage.